# Passing parameters to a PHP file included in an IMG tag

Tags: php, mysql

I have two files [ Main.html ] and [image.php]. However [image.php] is dealing with binary data since it displays an image from the database. My question is can I and if i can how do I pass parameters into [image.php] from main?

I call image.php in main like this:

> img src="image.php" alt="image retreived from DB"

```
<?php
$mysqli=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','draftdb');
if (!$mysqli)
die("Can't connect to MySQL: ".mysqli_connect_error());


    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT display.PICTURE_ID 
    FROM cards  
    INNER JOIN display ON cards.DISPLAY_ID = display.DISPLAY_ID 
    WHERE display.DISPLAY_ID=? AND cards.CARD_TYPE =?" );

     if( rand(1, 8) == 8) 
     {
     $cardtype='Mythic';
     $displayid=rand(1,15) ;

     }

     else
     {
     $cardtype='Rare';
    $displayid=rand(16,19) ;
     }

    $stmt->bind_param("si", $displayid, $cardtype);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($image);
    $stmt->fetch();
    header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
    echo $image; 
    ?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kind of hard to make a really detailed answer here, since the simplest solution is well... simple.

Surely you've seen website addresses with `?` and `var=value&var2=anothevalue` in them

You can do the same thing yourself with.

`<img src="image.php?param=wat&moreparam=lolz" />`

and

`$param = isset($_GET['param']) ? $_GET['param'] : null;`

Comment: This is the standard way to pass data to a page that you're going to display inline as an image. If for some reason it's not appropriate to put the data in a query string, it's also possible to send a POST request. Here's an explanation from the jpgraph documentation: http://jpgraph.net/download/manuals/chunkhtml/ch13s03.html (note: I haven't tested this personally).

Comment: @octern He's literally asking how to pass parameters from main.html to image.php. I don't think it needs to be complicated.

Comment: As far as I know, this is another valid way to do it. Probably more trouble than it's worth outside of very specific circumstances, though. (btw, I did vote up your answer. It's definitely the right one.)

Comment: I was just curious if it was possible since image.php is only dealing with binary data, if I could pass it parameters that are strings and ints, etc. I'll try it out thanks

Comment: @Undermine2k the parameters you pass via POST and GET are always strings (even if those strings have only digits in them).

Answer (score 1):

as usuall

```
img src="image.php?data=hello"
```

then in image.php

```
$_GET['data']
```